# Passing Data From Parent View Controller to Child View Controller Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, segue, parent-child

I am trying to send data from parent view controller (Container View) to its child view controller.

I've tried sending data via segue but I got this error
" Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10d30d1f0) to 'ContainerDeom.ChildVC' "

ContainerDeom: is the project name

ChildVC: The child of container view

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: It's solved! the problem was I didn't check the 'Inherit modeule from targer' in the custom class section of the ViewController. Also I've check the segue identifier name before passing data in 'prepare for segue' function.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
if let controller = (self.childViewControllers.filter {$0 is urChildController}).first {
    // assign ur parsed data of parent controller to your child controller 
    controller.dict = self.urResponseDict

}
```

Comment: It's solved! the problem was I didn't check the 'Inherit modeule from targer' in the custom class section of the ViewController. Also I've check the segue identifier name before passing data in 'prepare for segue' function.

Comment: @NouraAziz ur welcome and kindly mark as correct these answer if it helps to you :)